# Find process id of process on Solaris which is deleted the files

Tags: solaris-10

We have a Solaris 10 server. Lately, some of the files and folders are getting deleted from the server in once in a day like fashion. We haven't run any such programs to delete files.

Is there a way, that we can find the process id or name of this mysterious process which is responsible for deleting these files?